# get/set value of the ACF field by ACF JavaScript API, in a custom block, on the post editing page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I made a custom gutenberg block using the AdvancedCustomFields PRO plugin. This block has a gallery field. I need to make a button that fills the gallery field with certain photos. I render button using a new custom field type, but how to change the value of another field in the same block?

Function `acf.findFields (args)` in the ACF JavaScript API works well with fields that are attached to the page, but how I can access the field in a specific custom block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution
Append this script to admin panel
This code adds a button for the ACF gallery field that fill the gallery with a predefined data.

```
(function($){
    setInterval(function() {
        let fields = acf.getFields({type:"gallery"});
        for (let field of fields) {
            if (!field.dasupdated) {
                field.dasupdated = true;
                let control = $("<div><button class='button'>Append Attachment</button></div>");
                control.find("button").click(()=>{
                    field.appendAttachment({attributes:{
                        id: 56060, 
                        url: "http://site.url/image.jpg"
                    }});
                });
                $(field.$el[0]).find(".acf-gallery-main .acf-gallery-toolbar").append(control);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
})(jQuery);
```